# Simple JQuery Selector

Tags: jquery, html

Given the following HTML structure:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="top">
        <a href="http://example.com" class="link">click here</a>
    </div>
    <div id="middle">
        some text
    </div>
    <div id="bottom">
        some text
    </div>
<div>
```

How would I select the bottom div (div#bottom) using JQuery when a user clicks on the link in the top div (div#top)? There will be several of these divs on the page, so I can't just use `$('#bottom')`. `$(this).next('#comment-form')` also did not work.

Comment: There better not be several `#bottom` elements on that page, `id` attributes **must** be unique within each page or you'll get lots of odd things happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that you're duplicating `id` attributes. Don't do that, use classes instead:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="top">
        <a href="http://example.com" class="link">click here</a>
    </div>
    <div class="middle">
        some text
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        some text
    </div>
<div>
```

Your `id` attributes must be unique within each page or you have invalid HTML and things won't work very well.

Once you've fixed your HTML, things will go much easier:

```
$('.link').click(function() {
    var $bottom = $(this).closest('.wrapper').find('.bottom');
    // And now do whatever you need to do with your $bottom.
});
```

The [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) function goes up the DOM tree until it finds a match for the supplied selector, then [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find) comes back down to get the `.bottom` element.

Comment: "And now do whatever you need to do with your $bottom" - made me giggle :-)

Answer (score 2):

If there will be several 'bottoms' on the page, don't give them each an ID of "bottom" -- IDs should be unique. Instead, give them classes:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="top">
        <a href="http://example.com" class="link">click here</a>
    </div>
    <div class="middle">
        some text
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        some text
    </div>
<div>
```

Then the jQuery will look like:

```
$('div.top > a').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings('div.bottom').html('Do something');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: + 1 thanks, this works great. just ended up picking what appeared to be the first answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change `id` to `class` for all of your divs. Then, in your click handler find the parent and select from there. You could do either of these:

```
$(this).closest(".top").siblings(".bottom");
$(this).closest(".wrapper").find(".bottom");
```